# Php doesn't catch next array element

Tags: php, laravel

I have this array :

```
array (
  'cfop' => '3',
  'cst' => NULL,
  'cstPis' => '2',
  'cstCofins' => '1',
)
```

And this code:

```
while ($t = current($taxes))
{
    $getkey = key($taxes);
    Log::debug($getkey);

    //$this->saveTaxes($getkey, $t, $add);

    $t = next($taxes);
}
```

ps: `$taxes` is the array

For some reason the `next` function doenst not pass the null value, so the log prints just cfop.

If i change the order like this

```
array (
  'cfop' => '3',
  'cst' => '2',
  'cstPis' => NULL,
  'cstCofins' => '1',
)
```

Logs will print `cfop` and `cst` but it does not reach the next value after NULL

Comment: Because `NULL` is considered `falsy` and your iterations stops.

Comment: Any reason to not just use a `foreach` loop here instead?

Comment: We might not have your full code but this code snippet could be very much simplified by a simple foreach loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`null` is a falsy value, so when you do `$t = current($taxes)`, that evaluates to something that is falsy, so that's why it stops executing.

If you want to iterate over each value, I'd advise a foreach loop instead.

```
foreach ($taxes as $key => $value) {
  Log::debug($key);
  // $this->saveTaxes($key, $value, $add);
}
```

Comment: but if i want to take the key name?

Comment: @SkullFire You can access the key by using `$key` from Chris' example.